# MySQL Workbench for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, mysql-workbench

I generally use MySQL Workbench for making my ER diagrams. Now, I have to make a diagram for SQL Server. Does Workbench have a SQL Server export feature? If not, are there free ER diagram software I should take a look at?

**EDIT 1: (screen shot)**

[image]

Comment: You can make your ER diagrams for MSSQL Server directly using MS SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: So no way to do this in Workbench (I'm most comfortable with this tool)? Is MS SQL Server Management Studio free?

Comment: You can use the express edition. Just google `sql server 2008 r2 express`.

Comment: Just a quick note: I'm assuming you want to generate the database from the ER diagram.

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm currently trying to find the option in Studio to create diagrams

Comment: If you are using the software I mentioned above, in the Object Explorer, under your database node, there should be a sub-node named `Database Diagrams` from where you can create a `new diagram`.

Comment: I update my question with a screen shot. I don't see `Database Diagrams`.

Comment: I guess you need to create your (empty) database first. Then create the diagram for it.

Answer (score 1):

Hake a look at [Database Diagram Tool for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/database-diagram.html) in dbForge Studio for SQL Server. It will help you to view and modify existing database online.

You can try this feature in free express or trial version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012(2010, 2008, like you want) to create a SQL Server database from diagrams. Also you can use workbrench to create a diagram from a existent SQL Server database.

Comment: Ok, with workbrench you just need go to "file -> create model"

Comment: And I can export the diagram into SQL CREATE for MS SQL?

Comment: no, you didn't do this. You can get the sql code from of the diagram and you could use it to go to a sql manager and create a ms sql express database.